# MySQL: get only first row of each Distinct record

Tags: mysql

is there a way to get the first(if there are more than one. see item # 1) title for each item and an empty string for the title column in case title doesn't exists (see the item # 2, there is no title)
here is the table schemas.

```
Items
    ---------------
    id | created_by
    ---------------
     1   xyz
     2   abc


elements
    -----------------
    id | name
    -----------------
     1    Title
     2    Description
     3    Type


elements_text
    ------------------------------------------
     id | item_id | elements_id | text
    ------------------------------------------
     1       1           1        test title
     2       1           1        second title
     3       1           2        description
     4       2           2        test desc
     5       2           3        first type
     6       2           3        second type
     7       2           2        another desc
```

Expected output

```
-----------------------------------------
 item_id | element_name | element_text
-----------------------------------------
    1          Title       test title
    2          Title       <EMPTY STRING>
```

Comment: what if for the item#2 if the `elements_id` exists for any row other than the first in that case also it would show `<EMPTY STRING>` ? Or its always the first row in the set which decides ?

Comment: It should show first row where `elements.id = Title` and if there is no entry for `Title`, it should show an empty string

Comment: Is this what you are looking at ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8b63/6 try this query with some more data and let me know if this works.

Comment: Glad it worked :-)